# 500 Internal Server error from Nginx 1.8

Tags: nginx

I have been researching and reading almost everything that has been presented to me via web search. It appears to be an easy yet, I am unable to solve this pain.

I have the load balancer checking for a `200OK` response as a health check from all the nodes in AWS. So in the nginx conf (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf`), I have the below entry as a location block

```
location /about {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
      try_files $uri /about.htm;
    }
```

The file `/usr/share/nginx/html/about.htm` is present. So, the idea is when some one do a GET on `https://server_name/about`, the content of the file `/usr/share/nginx/html/about.htm` will be presented. It conf was working with nginx 1.0.15, i upgraded to `nginx version: nginx/1.8.0` and since then it started. The error log for nginx shows the below for the infinite loop

```
2015/10/09 23:20:24 [error] 25078#0: *308 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/about.html", client: 10.22.32.108, server: server_name, request: "GET /about HTTP/1.1", host: "10.22.32.72"
```

As this URL (..../about) is failing the health checks failed and hence there is no traffic sent to this node.

Any advise??

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many issues related to the `try_files` directive in nginx & every one have a unique issue with this prick. So, i have the 2 nginx conf files under `/etc/nginx/conf.d` viz `default.conf` - which have the conf for HTTP traffic and `ssl.conf` - which have the conf for the HTTPS traffic. In my case, the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`is configured to redirect any HTTP request to HTTPS and the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf`takes care of the HTTPS transactions.

After installing nginx 1.8 from the nginx.org repo (i was on nginx 1.0.15, which is available in EPEL repo. EPEL doesnt have the later versions, which sucks!. I need to modify my Chef recipe for nginx now). The `http://server_name/about` & `https://server_name/about` starts to break.

Below is the original conf files prior to installing 1.8 (only the relevant location block i,e `/about`)

`default.conf & ssl.conf` have the same configuration for this location `/about`

```
location /about {
     add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
     try_files $uri /about.html;
    }
```

So, with the 1.8 version i had to change like this (**in both the files**)

```
   location /about {
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
     try_files $uri /about.html;
    }
```

Notice the `root`, nginx 1.8 seems to expect the $ROOT_DIRECTORY for nginx. Here is what the directive say as [per nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

```
Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing; the processing is performed in the current context. The path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and alias directives.
```

So after this was set in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf`, the root directive was missed to be set in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` .